# Nginx content-type setting

Tags: nginx, content-type

I have setup webserver(Nginx).
and I have deploy applications(charaset:Shift-Jis).

After deploy, accessed to applications But,There is not charset in Nginx returned response "Context-Type" header.
Could you teach me Nginx settings it.

I tried the under but it was useless.

**Settings**

```
# nginx.conf
server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myapp.com:8080/;
    charset Shift-Jis;
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
# for example (CSS)
・・・
real)content-type: text/css
hope)content-type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
・・・
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the request to a proxy. In this case Headers and Charset are set by the proxy. Set the proper encoding at your Proxy Application. You can override existing charset with: override_charset on;

```
charset utf-8;
override_charset on;
```

if you want to set the source charset too:

```
source_charset koi8-r;
```

Answer (score 1):

this is work to me.

```
charset utf-8;
charset_types *;
```

set `charset_types` value to (*)

Answer (score 0):

I use this config in nginx.conf.

```
http {
    map $sent_http_content_type $charset {
        default '';
        ~^text/ utf-8;
        application/javascript utf-8;
        application/rss+xml utf-8;
        application/json utf-8;
        application/geo+json utf-8;
    }
    
    charset $charset;
    charset_types *;
    
    ...
    
}
```